# Update the primary contacts email address

Tags: registration, azure-marketplace

I have an Issue with registering my company in the marketplace I am currently stuck as Unverified for using a free email service. (This was due to a browser autofill mistake during registration on the entry form. My account has been set as the primary contact holder)

I have tried to change this email our company email domain, using the process below but I am unable to find a Update page which will let me do this. I seam to be locked out and everything is redirected back to the Legal info page.

Ref:

1. Go to Partner Center dashboard (https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/home, navigate to Settings --> Partner Settings)
2. Go to “Partner profile" tab and click "Update" link next to "Legal business profile" page
3. Update information on "Legal business profile" page and hit submit.
4. Refresh “Partner profile” page to check the new status on “Verification status”.

[image: Screenshot of dashboard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I manged to solve this was to create a microsoft support request. It helped writing a question in Stackoverflow because I referenced this question the request. They helped me in a few days.